# Why do USB devices need enumeration if they can be uniquely identified by bus and hub port?

Tags: linux, usb

By messing around in Linux /sys filesystem, one can find all USB devices in directories whose names represent the physical addreses of the USB devices.

```
ls /sys/bus/usb/devices
1-0:1.0  1-1  1-1:1.0  1-2  1-2:1.0  2-0:1.0 usb1  usb2
```

Now, from [this site](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-13-sect-2) i found out that the numbers represent the physical path to the device, including any hub on the way:

> As the devices go further down in the USB tree, and as more and more
> USB hubs are used, the hub port number is added to the string
> following the previous hub port number in the chain. For a two-deep
> tree, the device name looks like:
>
> root_hub-hub_port-hub_port:config.interface

So the question is, why do USB devices go through enumeration (and get assigned volatile numbers by the OS) if they already have a unique way of being identified, that is, the bus, hub and port numbers?

Comment: Why use a hostname even though the network has to actually locate that host by the IP address and then the MAC address of its Ethernet interface?  Which is more user-friendly and descriptive?

Answer (score 4):

I think there is some confusion. The Linux funny numbers seems to be LOGICAL HANDLES to USB devices, and they are formed after the physical enumeration process is done. Physical USB addresses have no resemblance with the handle names you listed, they are numbers from 1 to 127 that are embedded in every USB packet, anything in that range.

The original USB (1.1 and 2.0) is designed as "star topology", where all packets are BROADCASTED to all USB devices in the tree. Therefore the devices must have unique addresses that are assigned to them in the process of enumeration, to be able to decode proper streams. Although the system does know all the hubs and ports where the devices are connected to, it does not determine the packet's route, there is no information in USB packets about hub/port numbers, only device addresses. This however could be different for USB 3.0 architecture where packets can be explicitly routed by hub/port number, but the enumeration process is still required for backward compatibility reasons.